# XMLHttpRequest cannot load with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to retrieve a JSON response from my MongoDB and using it to plot a graph with `chartJS`. using this code

```
myurl = "http://localhost:5000/api/humidity"
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: myurl,
       // cache: false,
        dataType : "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
})
```

Unfortunately I keep getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load` error or `404 not Found`

This is my JSON data

```
[{"_id":"585b544f5c86b6c8537c34d6","topic":"Humidity","message":23,"when":"2016-12-22T04:19:27.000Z"}]
```

I have used various browsers seeing that Chrome has an issue with `XMLHttpRequest`

I will appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What is the full error message? The details are important and you should have no problem searching the terms used

Comment: Does `http://localhost:5000/test` work when you put it in the address bar of your browser?

Comment: is the page "served" by `http://localhost:5000/` as well, or is the page from a different host?

Comment: `Chrome has an issue with XMLHttpRequest` - no it doesn't

Comment: @charlietfl [this is the error I guess from web console] http://i64.tinypic.com/i1e3ko.png

Comment: @FabianSchultz No it doesn't work. The page is served by `http://localhost:5000` Could this be the problem?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it is.

Comment: Your main problem is not enabling CORS for cross origin requests

Comment: Yes, your server is not working properly. Your request on the client works, but the server is not there to handle it.

Comment: @charlietfl how can I enable CORS? do you have a link that could help?

Comment: @FabianSchultz what do you suggest I do ?

Comment: depends on server type. This is very easy to research

Comment: @charlietfl Basically i'm trying to feed my JSON response from my MongoDB to plot a chart.

Comment: Are any messages printed at `terminal`? Can you include contents of `"http://localhost:5000/test"` at Question? Are you using `php` to serve local files?

Comment: @Ekom the issue is with your code,  not with chrome

Comment: @FabianSchultz changing the URL to `http:localhost:5000` removed the error but unfortunately my data is not showing up in my console log.

Comment: @guest271314 Apparently my URL was wrong just fixed it. I'm using HTML5

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks a million guys. I was using the wrong URL.